# How do I use python to merge 2 excel spreadsheets based on common identifier?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, merge

I am trying to merge two datasets into one based on a unique identifier. In one spreadsheet I have a list of patients and some info e.g. admission dates. In the other, I have a list of drugs they have received, along with the unit in the hospital etc. Each has a unique medical identifier that ties them together. How can I use python to add all the drugs administered to a patient to the main spreadsheet, ideally in one column labelled 'drugs'?

I have tried the following, but it hasn't placed them into an individual column, and there doesn't seem to be a pattern in how it handles dates. Instead, it has created multiple copies of the patient. It also has seems like it has not copied across any patients that do not exist in both of the original files.

```
import pandas as pd
%pylab inline

drug_df = pd.read_excel(
    'C:/Users/Documents/Antibiotic Data.xls',
    parse_dates=[7, 8, 11, 17, 18],
    infer_datetime_format=True)
main_df = pd.read_excel(
    'C:/Users/Documents/Main Data.xls'
    parse_dates = [2, 3, 4],
    infer_datetime_format = True)
merged = drug_df.merge(main_df, on="MRN")
merged.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

Here is a link to some very basic spreadsheets that should give you an idea of what I'm starting and ending up with.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!ApoCMYBhswHzhokWfC6UILHhEqV_eA

Any hints how to move forwards from here?

Thanks,

Callum

Comment: While you can do this with pandas, you may want to take a look at the [petl](http://petl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package, I find it easier to do the ETL using it.

Comment: A minimal working data set would be helpful.  It sounds like your question is more complicated than you are stating. I am assuming that each admission date can have more than one drug administered during it. Depending on how your data is structured you can end up with all kinds of things going on.  Definitely will need an example for this.

Comment: Please include some data sample.